# RxJava UndeliverableException how to handle onSuccess consumer exception?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

The exception ended up not handled and was reported as a non-fatal in Crashlytics, hence fell off our radar
User saw a blank screen which is not desirable
A crash would have been better, for fail-fast is preferred

Ideally, I'd like to the `onError` consumer to be trigger, that's where I handle the error e.g. shows error UI for every stream

However,

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Single.just(listOf("efaewf"))
            .subscribe({
                println("result is ${it[1]}")
            }, {
                println("handling exception")
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
}
```

shows that `onError` consumer is not working

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3589)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt.main(Dummy.kt:7)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt.main(Dummy.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.get(Collections.java:4817)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt$main$1.accept(Dummy.kt:8)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt$main$1.accept(Dummy.kt)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3589)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt.main(Dummy.kt:7)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt.main(Dummy.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.get(Collections.java:4817)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt$main$1.accept(Dummy.kt:8)
    at com.coffeemeetsbagel.DummyKt$main$1.accept(Dummy.kt)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62)
    ... 5 more
```

I've read [the docs here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling) but don't comprehend fully

I could totally add `if {} else {}` or `try {} catch {}` to `onSuccess` consumer but it feels like code smell

Am I wrong, is if else/ try catch the best and/ or intended way to handle exceptions in `onSuccess`?

Comment: The `onError()` consumer is used when the exception happens in the source itself, not when it happens in your `onNext()` handler. Please edit your question to include the actual problem you have in handling exceptions in your `onNext()` handler (and/or your `onError()` handler).

Comment: Thanks, updated the question, is the problem clearer @Progman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Single` which has the protocol `onSuccess | onError`. So if `onSuccess` crashes, it can't invoke `onError` on the same observer.

In contrast, `Observable` has the protocol `onNext* (onError|onComplete)?` so a crashing `onNext` is then allowed to invoke `onError`.

You have a few options with `Single`:

- convert it to `Observable` before the subscribe,
- add try-catch in the unreliable `onSuccess` handler,
- do mapping/transformation in an earlier operator, such as `map`, so the end consumer is unlikely to crash.